# Is it possible to control how a function will be executed in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I know python is extremely flexible allowing -almost- anything user wants. However I have never seen nor heard of such a feature, and could not find anything related online: is it possible to execute a variable that is a function step by step?

```
def example_function():
  print("line 1")
  # stuff
  print("line 2")
  # stuff
  return(3)

def step_by_step_executor(fn):
  while fn.has_next_step():
    print(fn.current_step)
    fn.execute_step()
  return fn.return

step_by_step_executor(example_function) 
# print("line 1")
# line 1
# stuff
# print("line 2")
# line 2
# stuff
# return(3)
# returns 3
```

I think I can implement something like this using a combination of `inspect`, `exec` and maybe `__call__`, but I am interested to see if there is an already existing name and implementation for this.

Example use cases:

```
@do_y_instead_of_x
def some_function():
  do stuff
  do x
  do more
some_function()
# does stuff
# does y
# does more

@update_progress_bar_on_loops
def some_other_function():
  do stuff
  for x in range...:
     ...
  do more
some_other_function()
# does stuff
# initializes a progress bar, reports whats going on, does the loop
# does more
```

Comment: Not sure if python has anything liket his built-in, but I think 'executor' is the common name for this mechanism. 

It's probably hard to find a good reference because this question is actually very general and different applications solve it in different ways. 

The theoretical answer to this question is probably a sequence/control/list monad.

Comment: The debugger maybe? With a Tcl/expect script driving it

Comment: You're describing [`pdb.runcall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.runcall).

Comment: Make your function a generator and yield values when you want a "stop".

Comment: @blhsing `pdb.runcall` looks like it is specifically intended for debugging. I'm not sure if this would impose any performance drawbacks. (I will check and consider this as a possible solution when I start coding this)

Comment: @ipaleka that wouldn't be generic, see example use cases I added

Comment: Depends on what "step by step" means. There are quite a few options to achieve this. You could maintain an interpreter instance per function and feed it instructions line by line. This is not far off how jupyter notebooks work.

Comment: @stacksonstacks I think executing it line by line would be fine. If desired user can always pick a specific line and execute it with the same kind of step_executor recursively in case needed. I would like to have this without having any side effects (for example if a function does access to a global variable or belongs to a class etc, it should still behave the same in each of its steps, Im not sure if this’d be possible with interpreter), also efficiency is a concern which probably limits the options quite a bit

Comment: This sounds very much like you'll want to leverage the debugger as others have mentioned

Comment: @MarkSetchell You don't need to use Tcl/expect to drive the debugger. The `pdb.Pdb` constructor takes `stdin` and `stdout` as parameters so you can feed it commands and retrieve outputs directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Python debugger `pdb.Pdb` instance and pass to it a custom file-like object that implements the `write` method to selectively output the code portions of the debugger output, and the `readline` method to always send to the debugger the `n` (short for `next`) command. Since the debugger always outputs the line that returns from a function twice, the second time of which is preceded by a `--Return--` line, you can use a flag to avoid outputting the redundant line of return:

```
import pdb

class PdbHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.returning = False

    def write(self, buffer):
        if buffer == '--Return--':
            self.returning = True

        # each line of code is prefixed with a '-> '
        _, *code = buffer.split('\n-> ', 1)
        if code:
            if self.returning:
                self.returning = False
            else:
                print(code[0])

    def readline(self):
        return 'n\n'

    def flush(self):
        pass

def example_function():
    print("line 1")
    print("line 2")
    return (3)

handler = PdbHandler()
print('returns', pdb.Pdb(stdin=handler, stdout=handler).runcall(example_function))
```

This outputs:

```
print("line 1")
line 1
print("line 2")
line 2
return (3)
returns 3
```

Answer (score 2):

How about [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) - it does more than people think and can be used to fundamentally represent coroutines and ordering - a feature perhaps more fundamental than it's use to build iterators. Your example:

```
def example_function():
    print("line 1")
    yield
    print("line 2")
    yield
    print("line 3")
    return 3

def step_by_step_executor(fn):
    res = fn()
    while True:
        try:
            print(next(res))
        except StopIteration as e:
            retval = e.value
            break
    return retval

print(step_by_step_executor(example_function))
```

Which results in

```
line 1
None
line 2
None
line 3
3
```

As the return value of the generator is given as the value of the stop iteration that is raised. If you choose to intermittently `yield` values (instead of blank `yield`), you will see those printed at each iteration as well.

One common place where this kind of code comes up is the [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) `contextmanager` decorator which is used to turn a generator into a context manager though the series of enter and exit steps.

Comment: that would cause repetition of yield, and I wouldn't be able to pass any function (function specifically needs to have a yield in every second line). this would limit it's use for functions that come from third party libraries for example (see example use cases)

Comment: What about using `inspect.getsource(f)` and adding said yields, executing the result then with the above step_by_step_executor. A bit hacky. Using a debugger may make sense.

Comment: If it gets to implementing myself, I was thinking getting the source and using exec for each line, but that would work too

Comment: as long as you can adequately control the scope of the arguments

Comment: This simply isn't a safe solution. Unless you fully parse the code it is going to be hard for you to identify the end of a "line" to insert a `yield` statement into when the line is part of a multi-line statement.

Comment: @blhsing agreed